# Getting error parsing xsd into c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Here is the XSD I am using (downloaded straight from source)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.newyorkfed.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/V2_1/fundRate" xmlns:dsd="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/structurespecific" xmlns:common="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common" xmlns:codes="http://www.newyorkfed.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/V2_1/fundRateCommon" targetNamespace="http://www.newyorkfed.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/V2_1/fundRate" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/structurespecific" schemaLocation="SDMXDataStructureSpecific.xsd"/>
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common" schemaLocation="SDMXCommon.xsd"/>
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.newyorkfed.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/V2_1/fundRateCommon" schemaLocation="fundRateCommon.xsd"/>
 <xs:complexType name="RateDataSetType">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:TimeSeriesDataSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="DataProvider" type="common:DataProviderReferenceType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Group" type="GroupType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="Series" type="RateSeriesType" form="unqualified" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="SupplementalDataSetType">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:TimeSeriesDataSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="DataProvider" type="common:DataProviderReferenceType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Group" type="GroupType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="Series" type="SupplementalSeriesType" form="unqualified" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="GroupType" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="GroupType.ID" use="optional"/>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##local"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:simpleType name="GroupType.ID">
  <xs:restriction base="common:IDType">
   <xs:enumeration value="RateSiblingGroup"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="SupplementalSiblingGroup"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="RateGroup"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="SupplementalGroup"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
 <xs:complexType name="RateSiblingGroup">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="DECIMALS" type="codes:SDMX.CL_DECIMALS.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TITLE" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="GroupType.ID" use="optional" fixed="RateSiblingGroup"/>
    <xs:attribute name="UNIT_MEASURE" type="codes:SDMX.CL_UNIT_MEASURE.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="UNIT_MULT" type="codes:SDMX.CL_UNIT_MULT.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="LAST_DAY_OF_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="SupplementalSiblingGroup">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="DECIMALS" type="codes:SDMX.CL_DECIMALS.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_SUPPLEMENTAL" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_SUPPLEMENTAL.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TITLE" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="GroupType.ID" use="optional" fixed="SupplementalSiblingGroup"/>
    <xs:attribute name="UNIT_MEASURE" type="codes:SDMX.CL_UNIT_MEASURE.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="UNIT_MULT" type="codes:SDMX.CL_UNIT_MULT.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="RateGroup">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="COLL_METHOD" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="GroupType.ID" use="optional" fixed="RateGroup"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="SupplementalGroup">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="COLL_METHOD" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="GroupType.ID" use="optional" fixed="SupplementalGroup"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="RateSeriesType">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:TimeSeriesType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Obs" type="ObsType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="FREQ" type="codes:SDMX.CL_FREQ.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="SupplementalSeriesType">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:TimeSeriesType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Obs" type="ObsType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="FREQ" type="codes:SDMX.CL_FREQ.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_SUPPLEMENTAL" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_SUPPLEMENTAL.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FUNDRATE_TYPE" type="codes:FRBNY.CL_FUNDRATE_TYPE.1.0" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="ObsType">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:restriction base="dsd:TimeSeriesObsType">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="common:Annotations" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="CONF_STATUS_OBS" type="codes:SDMX.CL_CONF_STATUS_OBS.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="OBS_STATUS" type="codes:SDMX.CL_OBS_STATUS.1.0" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="OBS_VALUE" type="xs:decimal" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TIME_PERIOD" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="LAST_DAY_OF_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="REPORTING_YEAR_START_DAY" type="xs:gMonthDay" use="prohibited"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

When I run XSD to code I get this error:

[image]

I've tried adding complex type elements at the base level that define each one with a name and type property and this didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please show the error as text, not in an image. The XSD you show has many dependencies which makes it impossible to say whether the XSD code is valid.

Comment: have you tried validating the XSD try this link as see if it's valid or not http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VrzHnvkrKHs

Comment: Says it's invalid however this is where I've downloaded it from - https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/effr-obfr Seems like it should be valid coming from a legit source that is widely used, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you lack some of the necessary XSD documents. On the web page you link to in the comments: https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/effr-obfr, two XSD files can be obtained: `fundRateCommon.xsd` and `fundRate.xsd`.

But in `fundRate.xsd`, there are several `import` statements:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/structurespecific" schemaLocation="SDMXDataStructureSpecific.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common" schemaLocation="SDMXCommon.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.newyorkfed.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/V2_1/fundRateCommon" schemaLocation="fundRateCommon.xsd"/>
```

and from this page, you could not have downloaded `SDMXCommon.xsd` and `SDMXDataStructureSpecific.xsd`. The error you get from XSD2Code appears to be about content from `SDMXDataStructureSpecific.xsd`.

Download those XSD files, too and try again.

Comment: Do they just have to be in the same path when I use the generation tool?

Comment: @Scott I am not familiar with XSD2Code or C# - I don't know whether the tool can search intelligently for missing files. But yes, put them in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the base SDMX .xsd's.. these are available from
sdmx.org under the standards tab...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11450070)

Comment: @AndreiM This does provide an answer to the question.